# Adding multiple records for the collection of data using a single method

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there the possibility that one way to save a few records in the database collection.
I wish that every phone number "Name" and "Number" to save as a separate record in your own "_id" number.

Use the "addPhone" adds another form allows you to add additional phone number.

Here is my html code:

```
<form id="phones" class="col s12">

<div class="section">
 <h5>Phones</h5>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s7">
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="number">Number</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <a data-action="removePhone" class="btn-flat"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s7">
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="number">Number</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <a data-action="removePhone" class="btn-flat"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
  </div>
</div>


<a data-action="addPhone" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Add phone</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution to this problem is to package batch-insert